# Action Delegates in F#

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

In the Giraffe library examples, I noticed the following:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
        .ConfigureServices(configureServices)
        .Build()
        .Run()
    0
```

While I understand most of it, I'm unclear with `Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)` - is `configureApp` being cast to an `Action<IApplicationBuilder>`?

**UPDATE**

As I understand constructor calls, per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors):

> You initialize your objects together with constructor arguments,
>   either by **listing the arguments in order and separated by commas and
>   enclosed in parentheses**, or by **using named arguments and values in
>   parentheses**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is creating a new delegate, using the delegate constructor like an F# function.  The C# equivalent would be:

```
.Configure(new Action<IApplicationBuilder>(configureApp))
```

Comment: Has F# always allowed using constructors as functions? I was under the impression that parentheses were required to instantiate an object (see update in post).

Comment: Constructing union types uses the same mechanisms. ``Some 1`` is a call to the constructor of Some. I can't say how long F# supports this, but is't been there a while...

Comment: @Ari - It was added in F# 4.0: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/fsharp4/CHANGELOG.md